Blackboard math font that is compatible with mlmodern
With mlmodern, the mathbb font looks like

It looks very thin. Is there a way to make it look thicker and more in place with the rest of the font? The mathbf alternative looks very out of place.

MLModern unfortunately does not provide a blackboard version. NewCM (https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern?lang=en) provides blackboard letters in slightly heavier weight than normal LM/CM, in the NewCM-Book fonts. They are not as heavy as MLModern, but heavier than LM/CM. I also understand that a revised version of NewCM fonts, including updates to the blackboard fonts, is expected to arrive soon.

Edit:
In the recently released version 6.0.0, the uppercase Latin characters were redesigned in a hollow Computer Modern fashion, similar to the AMSbb letters.

Since the New Computer Modern fonts contain a true bold math font as well, they contain emboldened versions of the doublestruck letters as well.
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth, convert={density=7000}]{standalone}

\usepackage[newcmbb]{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \mathversion{bold}
    \(\mathbb{ABCDEFGJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\)
\end{document}


You have to use the \mathversion{bold} toggle the math font to bold when using the fontsetup package. \mathversion{normal} shall make it return to the normal math fonts. If you don't use the fontsetup package, then you have to manually define a bold math font. The option newcmbb to the fontsetup package makes the doublestruck letters compatible with Computer Modern.

Some other fonts, such as XITS and many of Daniel Flipo's fonts, such as Concrete Math, Erewhon Math, XCharter Math, Kpfonts offer a bold math variant as well, which contain emboldened doublestruck letters. I shall add them to this answer in due course of time.

I don't really know how to use the OpenType math fonts with a T1 encoded font, that is mlmodern.

Look at the mathalpha package for a variety of blackboard bold fonts. Here's an example with the extra bold variant (bfbb option) of the boondox fonts.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage[bb=boondox,bfbb]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
Some text and math: $\mathbb{ABC}$

$x\in\mathbb{R}$ is a real number.
\end{document}



I tried using it and it gave me the error "Font U/mthrb/b/n/10=mt2hrbdt at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found." How to make it work?

@ultralegend5385 You should ask a new question with a MWE showing the error
